# Алгоритм определения того что программа запущена на виртуальной машине

Tags: c++, windows, python-3.x

Есть программа для работы с которой необходимо авторизоваться ... Задача ... Необходимо на одной машине запустить несколько виртуальных машин и на каждой запустить нужный софт и на каждой войти в один из доступных аккаунтов. Вероятность того что аккаунт будет забанен весьма велика...аккаунты прокачены(потрачено много времени)...мои вопросы о ситуации...по каким признакам можно определить что ОС( Win7,10)виртуальна? В какую сторону рыть решение? Какие есть методы определения того что софт запущен на виртуальной машине?

Прочитал https://xakep.ru/2013/11/08/61563/... статья интересная. На 2017 год наверное системы защиты усовершенствовались...буду признателен за более современные источники знаний по описанной задаче.

*Я только вхожу в программирование (Python,C++)...это скорее тестовое задание самому себе.*

Comment: Вроде авторы виртуальных машин общего назначения и не ставили задачу сокрытия их существования. Ведь их задача — обеспечение среды для выполнения гостевых ОС, но никак не предоставление неограниченных отладочных возможностей хостовой системе.

Comment: Это Вам нужно определить, что Вашу программу запустили с виртуальной машины или Вы боитесь, что сервер обнаружит клиента, запущенного на виртуальной машине?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov  боюсь что сервер обнаружит клиента запущенного на виртуальной машине

Comment: Если клиент Ваш, то не обнаружит

Comment: В `systemd` есть утилита `systemd-detect-virt`, которая как раз возвращает тип виртуалки. Можно посмотреть сорцы и выяснить как это реализовано у линукса.

Comment: @donRumata  ваш комментарий очень полезный,буду вникать... Спасибо большое!!!

Comment: внесу 5 копеек. я не знаю, детали задачи, но меня настораживает, что все виртуальные машины будут обращаться через разные аккаунты к одному и томуже сервису, с одного сетевого адреса. Не будет ли определенное количество обращений с одного ip спусковым крючком для проверки со стороны сервера?

Comment: к каждой VM  прикручен уникальный сетевой интерфейс

Answer (score 1):

Абсолютно надежного способа определить все виртуальные машины, IMHO, нет. Дальше - цитата из приведенной статьи, которая, внезапно, актуальности не потеряла и по сей день:

> виртуальная машина несет на своем борту какое-нибудь специфическое оборудование.

От нее и пляшите, VM в стандартной конфигурации поймаете.

Comment: То что статья актуальна это радует, буду экспериментировать... спасибо